# For which polynomials $P$ does there exist a polynomial $Q$ such that $P(x)=Q(x)Q'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, functional-equations

I am wondering for which polynomials $P$ does there exist a polynomial $Q$ such that $P(x)=Q(x)Q'(x)$? I am quite sure a complete characterisation will be very hard, but I'm looking for partial results as well.

Clearly, if $P$ has one term, then $P$ has to have odd degree, since the degree of the right handed side is odd. The following example shows that in fact all such polynomials with positive coefficients work:

We see that $Q(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{n}}x^n$ gives $Q'(x)=\sqrt{mn}x^{n-1}$ gives $ Q(x)Q'(x)=mx^{2n-1}$. If we require $Q$ to have real coefficients then this only works for $m>0$.

We may also take $Q(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{n}}x^n+C$, this will give $P(x)=ax^{2n-1}+bx^{n-1}$ for all real $a>0$ and all real $b$. I conjecture this are the only two-term polynomials $P$ that statistify, because if we change $Q$, then the product $Q\cdot Q'$ will probably have too many terms.

Comment: It may help to rewrite the equation as $P(x)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(Q(x))^2$.

Comment: do you want to get a complete caracterization in terms of the coefficients of $P$? otherwise I would suggest those $P$ such that there exists another Polynomial $T$ such that $P=\frac{1}{2}\left(T^2\right)'$, but that might be a bit too obvious as caracterization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not that hard: the antiderivative of $P(x)$ should be a square.

Comment: Half a square, to be precise (makes no difference for $\Bbb R[X]$, but does make a difference for $\Bbb Q[X]$ or $\Bbb Z[X]$)

Comment: Yes, sure. I was thinking about $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Wow, I completely missed that. One question: I guess that means that an antiderivative of $P$ should be a square? Not neccesarily the one with $C=0$, where $C$ is the constant of integration?

Comment: Sure, that should be just one of them, with one specific C, not necessarily 0.